# focusout() is not functioning using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm attempting to evaluate the length of the content within an input field. If the length of the content is 0, I want to apply some CSS styles.

> When I remove the if statement, this function works on focus out. Can
>   you see where I've gone wrong with my syntax?

```
$( "input" ).focusout(function() {                   
     var n = $( "input" ).length;                   
     if (n == 0) {                   
         $( '.enteremail' ).css( "transform", "translateY(0px)");                   
     }                   
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must check the input's value:

```
$('input').focusout(function() {
     // Check the value of the affected ("this") input
     var n = $(this).val().length;
     if (n === 0) {                   
         $('.enteremail').css('transform', 'translateY(0px)');                   
     }                   
});
```

not the number of input fields in the document

Answer (score 3):

`$( "input" ).length` will return the number of inputs in the current docuent.

You need first to use the `this` keyword to target the current input that is losing the focus, then use the jQuery method `.val()` to return the value of the input before checking the length, like :

```
 $("input").focusout(function() {
      if ( $(this).val().length ) {                   
          $( '.enteremail' ).css( "transform", "translateY(0px)");                   
      }                   
 });
```